# Unable to upload jquery-1.7.1.min for firefox addon using addon builder

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to load jquery into `Data` folder of my firefox addon, but whenever I try to upload it it gives an error `ERROR 403 FORBIDDEN 'Attachment failed to save properly Unknown Unicode in file`.

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Add-on Builder expects all text files to be in UTF-8, there does seem to be some bug when uploading files from local disk however. It works fine if you upload from URL and enter http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js there.

Related bug reports (supposedly all resolved):

- [Bug 699192](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=699192)
- [Bug 708372](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=708372)

Comment: I had also seen this error when sing Google's hosted jquery, but the version from jQuery.com always worked.